# Import a .so lib in Unity that is created on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, shared-libraries, .so

I have to write a dynamic shared library for android (.so) and use it in Unity. I tried using the .so file that is exported from Android Studio when coding with JNI but Unity can't read the library.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class ShareApp : MonoBehaviour {
    int cntr=0;

#if UNITY_ANDROID
    [DllImport("SharedObject2")]
    private static extern int getFrameNumber();
#endif
...
}
```

the error message Unity returns is:

> DllNotFoundException: SharedObject2

while the name of the library in unity's Assets/Plugins is libSharedObject2.so.

I tried building the library with Visual Studio 2015, using the cross platform Dynamic shared library (Android) option for a new project. Results are the same. The .so file is built but unity fails to read it.

The .cpp file I use to built the .so file contains just this:

```
extern "C"
{
    int getFrameNumber()
    {
        return 5;
    }

}
```

Can anyone please point me to a direction?

Comment: I had used library file along with .so file for one of my projects. In this case there was a lib file as well as .so file. Both these I pasted in lib folder with .so file under a sub folder (name I dont remember). Now the libraries where getting detected.